# $\min\{200x+100y\}$ such that $x+3y\geq12$, $3x+2y\geq12$, $x\geq0,y\geq0$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

$\min\{200x+100y\}$ such that $2x+3y\geq12$, $3x+2y\geq12$, $x\geq0,y\geq0$

***Attempt.*** I am using the lagrangian approach to attack this problem and I know the optimal solution is $(0,6)$, but I cannot get this from the following approach, please enlighten me where did it gone wrong.

$$L=200x+100y-\lambda(2x+3y-12)-\mu(3x+2y-12)\\
L_x=200-2\lambda-3\mu=0\\
L_y=100-3\lambda-2\mu=0\\
\lambda(2x+3y-12)=0\\
\mu(3x+2y-12)=0
$$

Now we could dealt with four cases:

(1) $\lambda=\mu=0$, this is impossible by observing $L_x,L_y$

(2) $\lambda>0,\mu=0$ we have inconsistent

$$2x+3y-12=0\\\lambda=100\:\text{from}\:L_x,\lambda=\frac{100}{3}\:\text{from}\:L_y$$

(3) $\lambda=0,\mu>0$ similar case as (2)

(4) $\lambda>0,\mu>0$ we have $$\begin{cases}
        2x+3y=12\\
       3x+2y=12\\
     \end{cases}$$

so that $x=y=2.4$. **This solutions is incorrect!**

Comment: You have four constraints. Your optimum occurs at the intersection of constraints $x\ge0$ and $3x+2y\ge12$ as you can see if you draw the region. You know that the solution will occur either at $(0,6), (2.4,2.4)$ or $(12,0)$, the vertices of the constraint region.

Comment: @LJNG.- Your first constraint is in your tittle $x+3y\ge12$, is not $2x+3y\ge12$.